# Interface implementation with optional arguments

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

Take this interface:

```
interface ILogger
{
    void Store(string payload);
}
```

And this class implementation of `ILogger`:

```
class Logger : ILogger
{
    void Store(string payload, bool swallowException = true)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would anticipate the compiler would recognize `swallowException` as an optional argument, and thus satisfy the requirements of the interface. Instead, what happens is the compiler complains that `Logger` does not implement interface member `Store`.

Another interesting thing I tried was implementing the interface explicitly, like so:

```
class Logger : ILogger
{
    void ILogger.Store(string payload, bool swallowException = true)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The compiler gives a warning "The default value specified for parameter 'swallowException' will have no effect because it applies to a member that is used in contexts that do not allow optional arguments." It seems to suggest optional arguments are somehow incompatible with explicit interface definitions, but why?

I can work around the problem by overloading `Store` with two separate function definitions (the way of doing things before optional arguments existed). However I like optional arguments for their syntactic clarity and would prefer that this just worked the way I expect.

I understand there's probably a reasonable (historical or otherwise) explanation for why this is the way it is, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: In my 'Googling' I uncovered an enlightening blog article by Eric Lippert that seems to suggest an answer to my question, but it's still not quite clear to me. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because optional arguments in C# are just syntactic sugar.

The method definition in your case is

```
void Store(string payload, bool swallowException)
```

rather than

```
void Store(string payload)
```

Which obviously doesn't match the interface.

The way default arguments work is that the compiler injects the default values into the call of the method. So if you do `Store(payload)`, the compiler will actually emit `Store(payload, true)`. This is extremely important for understanding of default arguments - it's done in compile time of the caller. So if you change the default argument in the callee without recompiling the caller, the caller is still going to use the old default argument.

This also explains the warning you got - since the default value is passed by the compiler explicitly, and you can't call an explicit implementation of an interface without casting to the interface, you're not going to get an opportunity to use the default value, ever.

You don't actually want to use default arguments at all. Simply define two methods like this:

```
void Store(string payload, bool swallowException)
{
  // Do your job
}

void Store(string payload)
{
  Store(payload, true);
}
```

This avoids both of the problems above - the interface contract is satisfied, and the default argument is now part of the callee, not the caller.

Personally, I don't use optional arguments in public API methods at all - they're just aching to cause trouble when you decide that you want to change them at some point. Unless you can make sure they will *stay* the same forever, don't use them. The same applies to `const` and `enum` - both are also determined at compile-time, rather than run-time.

Remember, the reasoning for including default arguments is to allow you to *not pass* some argument. That makes sense for things like COM API calls (which would otherwise require you to pass all the arguments you don't want to pass as `Type.Missing`), or `null` values. Even using `false` is just asking for trouble when someone decides that a better default would be `true` - suddenly, some callers are using `true` and some `false`, although all think they're using the "default". For a case like yours, I'd use `bool?` instead, with a default value of `null` (or `default(bool?)`, whichever you prefer). In the method code itself, you can then easily handle the default at the proper point - say, by doing `swallowException.GetValueOrDefault(true)`.

Comment: I think I understand the mechanics of optional arguments better now. I see what you mean by the explicit interface definition needing to match the interface exactly. I should have realized it wouldn't make sense to use optional parameters here. My bad.

Comment: The explicit case aside, could the compiler not emit two function definitions on my behalf? In other words, have the compiler do the same thing you're suggesting I do "manually?" I think this would eliminate the problem you're describing where the caller has compiled with an out-of-date default. Is there some logical reason this wouldn't work that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Anyway, given how optional arguments work now, I think I will definitely follow your advice and NOT use optional parameters for public methods... I am enlightened! Thank you.

Comment: @JamesJones Of course it could. But that's not how optional arguments work :) I assume they wanted to avoid having to deal with overloads of those methods - there's only one overload, with the correct number (and types) of arguments. If they generated an overload for each,  that could clash with other methods defined on the type. And often, when you want to do this kind of "defaulting", it also involves some (simple) operations on the inputs, so it wouldn't be that useful. Importantly - named arguments. You can choose to ignore all the default arguments while picking the ones to pass.

Comment: @JamesJones The named arguments are also probably the strongest argument. Again, think of the COM method call where you have a method with 30 arguments (ever worked with Excel API? :)), and you only want to pass three of those, the rest are `Type.Missing`. If default arguments simply ensured there are 30 overload of the method, you wouldn't be able to cherry-pick which arguments to pass - they would always have to be in order.

Comment: I want to be flexible in the use of my three parameters. Want to be able to use any of them, any combination or none at all. Maybe I'll leave the method out of the interface.

Comment: @MrFox Just use defaults that you replace in the actual implementation. Your method will have three parameters (instead of having six methods, one each for every possible combination of the parameters), and the caller can choose which parameters to pass.